# Publishing a google form at given time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

As a TA in my university, I have to create an enrollment form for a student project. The enrollment will work on a "first come, first serve" basis and should start at 5 pm on a given day.

Is this a good solution to achieve this using google apps script and google form?

The problem is that the `onOpen()` trigger only works for me (i.e. in the *edit mode*). I actually could program it in such a way that I have an `onOpen()` function and then starting at 4:55 p.m. I use, e.g., the ReloadEvery addon in firefox.

I was also thinking about using a `ClockTriggerBuilder`, the problem is that, according to the docs,

> `atHour()` Specifies the hour the trigger will run (**plus or minus 15 minutes**).

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can't use an On Open trigger for your users.  If there is a limit to the **number** of responses, you can use the On Form Submit trigger, and count the number of responses every time that a Form is submitted, and then shut the Form off at the limit.  It is possible to set a trigger down to the minute using code, but whether you are guaranteed that it will run that minute is in question.  There is currently an Add-on for shutting down the Form at a certain date or number of responses, but I have not used it.  I'm working on an Add-on to turn the Form ON/ OFF.

Comment: @sandy No, there is no closed number, but rather a waiting list. I know about about addons for shutting a form down, but indeed one for ON/OFF appears to be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "open" the form at an specific time, set it to "Not accepting answers" (on the form 'Responses' tab), and then use an Apps Script date-time specific trigger to set it open on the desired time.

```
function openMyForm() {
  FormApp.openById('your-form-id').setAcceptingResponses(true);
}
```

[image]

Comment: That sounds good, but are you sure there won't be the same tolerance as I reported above (+/- 15min?). I will test it though.
For sake of completeness I will add the code needed for the *installed trigger*
`function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .create();
}`

Comment: Indeed, that's the equivalent of creating a time trigger using the `.at()` method and will also have the tolerance of +/-15min. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#at(Date)

Comment: Well, that seems to be pretty reliable. At least in my two tests it was +/- <30s precise

Comment: From my tests, when you specify down to the minute, it is executed under that minute ~30s. When using hourly or daily ones you may get a bigger range. But nice point there, the documentation is pretty relaxed on those terms :-/

Comment: Yes, indeed in the final application it worked well. The documentation is definitely too relaxed, or it is not specified in which case (if you just specify down to the hour?) this tolerance apply. I could've spared to ask on stackoverflow if this was the case ;-) Thanks again for your answer&time.